# Data bind loop knockout js , if I want to show only 2 names at a time from a list and then clicking on a button next 2 names comes up

Tags: css, html, knockout.js

I want to show only first 2 things which are present in an array instead of all and then b y clicking on button next 2 names comes up till the last, Can you help me in correcting the code of knoctout js .

```
<div class="slide">
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')" style="margin-top: -50px;margin-bottom: 1px;margin-left: 1020px;padding-right:5px;">Read more</button>
        <ul data-bind="foreach:EventBE.WhoElseAttends">
            <li >
                <span data-bind="text:FirstName"></span>
                <span data-bind="text:LastName"></span>,
                <span data-bind="text:Company"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>                  
  <span data-bind="if:EventBE.WhoElseAttends.length <0">No Attendees</span>                    
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript

```
EventBE.displayCount = ko.observable(2);
EventBE.readMore = function() { EventBE.displayCount(EventBE.displayCount() + 2); };
```

In HTML

```
<button type="button" data-bind"click: EventBE.readMore,
  visible: EventBE.displayCount() < EventBE.WhoElseAttends.length">Read More</button>

<ul data-bind="foreach:EventBE.WhoElseAttends.slice(0, EventBE.displayCount())">
```

This is just an example, you may also need to use a subscriber to reset `displayCount` when `WhoElseAttends` changes.

If your `WhoElseAttends` is `observableArray`, you need to fix `EventBE.WhoElseAttends.length` to `EventBE.WhoElseAttends().length`